# g++ 1000 times slower than visual studio using lists?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, optimization, stl, g++

Consider the following code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

#define NUM_ITER 100000

int main() {
    clock_t t = clock();
    std::list< int > my_list;
    std::vector< std::list< int >::iterator > list_ptr;

    list_ptr.reserve(NUM_ITER);

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_ITER; ++i) {
        my_list.push_back(0);
        list_ptr.push_back(--(my_list.end()));
    }

    while(my_list.size() > 0) {
        my_list.erase(list_ptr[list_ptr.size()-1]);
        list_ptr.pop_back();
    }

    cout << "Done in: " << 1000*(clock()-t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " msec!" << endl;
}
```

When I compile and run it with visual studio, all optimizations enabled, I get the output:

> Done in: 8 msec!

When I compile and run it with g++, using the flags

> g++ main.cpp -pedantic -O2

I get the output

> Done in: 7349 msec!

Which is rougly 1000 times slower. Why is that? According to the "cppreference" calling erase on a list is supposed to use up only constant time.

The code was compiled and executed on the same machine.

Comment: Is the clock returning what you think it is returning?

Comment: @tofutim Yes, I don't even need it to notice that the g++ executable takes way longer to terminate.

Comment: Same machine? or similar spec?

Comment: Yes, on the same machine.

Comment: How do you have Linux and VS on the same machine? Is one of them in a VM? Cygwin?

Comment: No, I compiled it with g++ under windows and it is slower there.

Comment: Where do you get g++ for windows?

Comment: @tofutim It is contained in mingw.

Comment: Isn't `list::size` allowed to be O(n) ? It may be that MSVC stores the size somewhere, and GCC does not (making the `while` loop O(n^2))

Comment: @AlexandreC.: I can't believe I overlooked that >.<   Confirmed, std_list.h in my implementation reads `{ return std::distance(begin(), end()); }`

Comment: C++11 mandates that size is O(1). Can you try with `-std=c++11` option ?

Comment: @AlexandreC. you are right. Storing the size makes g++ equally fast. Maybe you want to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It might be that the implementation shipped by GCC doesn't store the size, and the one MSVC ships does. In this case the inner loop is O(n^2) with GCC, O(n) for MSVC.

Anyway, C++11 mandates that list::size is constant time, you may want to report this as a bug.

Comment: +1 for pinpointing it. I've provided two workarounds in my answer (1 for this specific example and 1 using boost's `list`)

Comment: It might worth mentioning that gcc did not store the size as it was mandate by the C++98 standard so that we can have a constant time splice.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE** Workaround:

You can avoid calling `size()` so many times:

```
size_t my_list_size = my_list.size();
while(my_list_size > 0) {
    accum += *list_ptr[list_ptr.size()-1];
    my_list.erase(list_ptr[list_ptr.size()-1]);
    --my_list_size;
    list_ptr.pop_back();
}
```

Now it reports 10 msec.

**EDIT** 
Their list implementation isn't as efficient. I tried by replacing with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <boost/container/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/container/list.hpp>
using namespace std;

#define NUM_ITER 100000

int main() {
    clock_t t = clock();
    boost::container::list< int > my_list;
    boost::container::vector< boost::container::list< int >::iterator > list_ptr;

    list_ptr.reserve(NUM_ITER);

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_ITER; ++i) {
        my_list.push_back(rand());
        list_ptr.push_back(--(my_list.end()));
    }

    unsigned long long volatile accum = 0;

    while(my_list.size() > 0) {
        accum += *list_ptr[list_ptr.size()-1];
        my_list.erase(list_ptr[list_ptr.size()-1]);
        list_ptr.pop_back();
    }

    cout << "Done in: " << 1000*(clock()-t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " msec!" << endl;
    cout << "Accumulated: " << accum << "\n";
}
```

This now runs in ~0ms on my machine, vs. ~7s using std::list on the same machine.

```
sehe@desktop:/tmp$ ./test
Done in: 0 msec!
Accumulated: 107345864261546
```

Comment: It shouldn't be, `new` and `delete` have side effects don't they?

Comment: Done in: 20 msec!
Accumulated: 1643186939  (60Win7E, VC++12)

Comment: @Listing I have completely changed my answer: GNU std::list is just not efficient in this scenario

Comment: @sehe: That's so wierd.  I'm going to go rub this in the faces of those F/OSS guys.

Comment: @MooingDuck You go right ahead. I'm gonna profile _what_ is taking this time instead :)

Comment: Boost list taking 10ms on Coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8b1b28ed925472d

Comment: @sehe: I hope you're tracking the question comments because  Alexandre C. found it

Comment: @MooingDuck I have and I have put a measured a workaround just now in the answer :)

Comment: Since he's counting down to zero, wouldn't `.empty()` be better than tracking the size yourself?

Comment: I've done the simplest adaptation of the code. I'd argue that no matter how you spell the loop condition, this code won't win any awards :)

Comment: @sehe 10ms is just a minimal quantum this sort of measurement would return. In reality, the CPU time was less. Having said this, on my linux setup boost::container is about 8% faster than std for the example in question.

Comment: @oakad I know. I've reworded.